# How to disable touch scroll sound on Microsoft Arc Touch mouse in Linux?

Tags: mouse

The touch-to-scroll area on Microsoft Arc Touch Mouse makes an artificial scroll-wheel sound by default, which I find annoying. Disabling it seems problematic for Linux users as it requires Microsoft's Mouse and Keyboard Center, which is only available for Windows (XP to 10) and OS X (version 10.4-10.7).

Is it possible to disable the scroll-wheel sound on the Arc Touch Mouse using Linux only?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After much searching, I've found only one method to disable the touch feedback sound. Unfortunately, it requires a Windows PC. Although this does not answer my question in the OP body above, I thought I would share it anyway, for lack of a better solution:

1. Go to: https://www.microsoft.com/hardware/en-us/p/arc-touch-mouse#support
2. Select your Windows OS variant in the drop-down box
3. Download the Mouse and Keyboard Settings software
4. Plug the Arc Touch Mouse USB dongle into your Windows PC, then wait for drivers to install automatically
5. Install the software (ignore the reboot prompt, rebooting is not necessary)
6. Open the Mouse and Keyboard Settings, and look for the Vibration setting towards the bottom:

   [image: List item]
7. Disable the vibration setting by clicking the switch to the off setting.
8. Unplug mouse, and plug it into your Linux computer
9. Voila! No more artificial scroll-wheel sound!

I don't yet know of a way to do this under Linux only. I searched Github and Google for open-source alternatives to Microsoft's Mouse and Keyboard Settings, but have yet to find anything. You could try running the Mouse and Keyboard Settings application under WINE, but I have yet to test that.